# apply_filter doesn't get a chance to execute

Tags: wordpress, hook

There's a function get_comment_reply_link in the core WordPress files. It has a "apply_filters" statement at the end like this:

return apply_filters('comment_reply_link', $before . $link . $after, $args, $comment, $post);

Unfortunately, some checks within that function make it return under certain circumstances without ever reaching the "apply_filters" statement, so my custom function never runs at all! If I manually move the "apply_filters" line to the top, then it works fine.

Is this intended behavior? How do I run my own function when apply_filters never gets a chance to be called? Since I don't want to change the essential WordPress core, can I submit a request to the WordPress team to make this change?

Comment: How is `get_comment_reply_link` being called inside your theme?

Comment: It's called from within comment-template.php by comment_reply_link. http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L0

Answer (score 0):

put apply filters on the end of function php

Comment: Oh, if I do that then what value do I return? I want the filter to execute when the main function is running so that it returns my modified value. Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: you shouldn't need an output, it should change the wordpress default formats through out your entire site
i think you might be looking for this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter)

Comment: I want the original function to call apply_filters so that it will return a changed value instead. Putting apply_filters in functions.php doesn't work. I don't know how it could...